Unable to format number in nodejs as euro currency
I don't seem to be able to format a number as euro currency in nodejs.
I tried multiple versions of nodejs (version 18 and 20) and same problem.
I want to display 100,00 €, but instead it displays €100.00.
I am running macOS 14.6.1.
I am unsure whether I need to install extra libraries like ICU or something else?
I want the following script to display 100,00 €, but instead it displays €100.00.
So I created a script.js file with the following content:
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(100));

If I run this in the browser, I get the correct formatting.
I have also ran it in https://stackblitz.com and got the correct formatting.
stackblitz screenshot
So when I run this script using the docker node images I do get the wrong formatting.
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:20 node script.js

the output:
€100.00

